# Applying for UK short-term study visa from another country of origin

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, poland, ukraine

I am a Ukrainian citizen, studying in Poland on a D-type visa that expires in September 2017. As well I am holding a residence permit in Poland that expires in August 2018. I was qualified for Erasmus exchange programme to study in the UK from September 2018 to December 2018. I was wondering if I could apply for short-term study Visa from Poland itself?